# How to draw sprite out without using draw() method in Windows Phone XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna-4.0

I'm developing windows phone game using xna framework.and I want to draw sprite outside of

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime){
}
```

method.can I do this or not?.if it is posible,how to do this?.
can I draw sprite within update method?
thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can draw a sprite wherever you want in your code. It is typically done in the Draw method for convenience and ease of use when drawing multiple things.

The update / Draw methods may also run at different rates.

Comment: I'm developing small game.sprite move top to bottom.and when one sprite come to bottom i draw it last position of bottom.when second sprite come it will draw,but first one is clear.I want to draw every sprite that come to bottom of screen.

Comment: Leave them in the draw method and add them to an a List when they reach the bottom. Simply draw the List whenever needed.

Comment: I want to draw one by one when sprite come to bottom.Ill try using list.thanks

Comment: _spriteBatch.Begin();
            _spriteBatch.Draw(_tileTextureStop, _rectForTextureStop, Color.White);
            _spriteBatch.End();

when i add this code out side of draw method nothing happen